# how to update a table if it is used in subquery

Tags: mysql

This MySQL query is throwing error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause
```

**I have tried all previously given answers but my problem is not solved please help.**

```
update myTable set total = total+1
where (x_id, y_id) in
(
select x_id, y_id
from xTable join myTable using(x_id)
where (x_code='NA-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=5))
or (x_code='PS-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=1))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple trick, but it can be slow:

```
update myTable set total = total+1
where (x_id, y_id) in
(
  SELECT * FROM
  (
  select x_id, y_id
  from xTable join myTable using(x_id)
  where (x_code='NA-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=5))
  or (x_code='PS-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=1))
  ) s
)
```

or you can use a JOIN:

```
update
  myTable INNER JOIN (
    select x_id, y_id
    from xTable join myTable using(x_id)
    where (x_code='NA-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=5))
    or (x_code='PS-204' and y_id in (select y_id from yTable where z_id=1))
  ) s
  ON myTable.x_id=s.x_id
     AND myTable.y_id=s.y_id
set
  myTable.total = myTable.total+1
```